# How to check percentage contribution from each contributier in the current codebase?

Tags: git, github

I would like to how in the current codebase (for example, the latest version of master branch) the percentage (base on number of line in current codebase, not number of commits) of each user's contribution.

For example,

100 lines in master branch

15% from User A
80% from User B
 5% from User C

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Gitinspector* solves my problem which shows the number of rows from each author that have survived and are still intact in the current revision.

https://github.com/ejwa/gitinspector